# How do I find which installed applications require the .NET framework on a server or workstation?

Tags: .net-framework, microsoft

My question is in regards to Microsoft .Net and trying to determine what installed applications require .Net.

Some background, during vulnerability scans we've identified several instances of Microsoft .Net that are SEoL and they need to go. In some cases there are however several other versions install along side these EoL versions. But I know that I just can't go and have admins to remove them without the possibility of breaking something, so I need a way to identify what apps use which versions, whether on a server or desktop, or via desktop to server via client.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 can only have a single version .NET 4.8.X installed.  If you are talking about .NET Core 5.x+ you need to give us a little more to work with to help you.  .NET Core like .NET Framework is backwards compatible.  This means having the current LTS version should be enough to run any .NET Core application provided it does not require a newer version.  As the Administrator on the system you are in the best position to determine which versions are required on the system.

Comment: I agree with the above.  You can use Powershell to check:  ........   Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version

Comment: @Ramhound: That's not necessarily true; Windows 10 [can certainly have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KRpA.png) other versions besides .NET 4.8.x installed, as programs that require e.g. .NET 2.0 won't run on 4.8.x.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the information you asked about is below.

Comment: @u1686_grawity - Yes;  I suppose .NET Framework 3.5 can be installed.  However, those versions, have not been supported for many years from a security perspective.  I was talking more about anything newer than 4.0 cannot be installed over 4.8

Comment: @DdJSR - Where?  Your question has not been modified.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy built-in way to see everything, but you can try starting with this on a per-process basis:

1. Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from Sysinternals to view process details
2. Open a current running process
3. Navigate to the .Net Assemblies Tab
4. See the CLR version

---

Or in powershell, you can run `(Get-Process -Name "Notepad").Modules.Filename` and look for loaded .NET assemblies and their versions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I think I'll use the powershell suggestion. A little background, I'm the security engineer [the guy everyone loves to hate], at this point I'm not too worried about the Windows 10 machines because they'll all be gone soon, but the 2016 and 2019 servers are a real problem. Our Windows 2022 servers are good because I've made the Admins document what they install, when and why.  

anyway, thanks again and I will come back and post how that turned out.

Don